# Redshift human-readable durations / equivalent to postgres `justify_interval`

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have duration values in microseconds in Redshift that I want to show in a reduced form, eg `49275177354` should appear as `13:41:15.177354` or something similarly human-readable.

The values can be anywhere from a few seconds to several hours, so the appropriate base unit will vary from row to row.

In postgres, I would handle this using `justify_interval` like this:

`select justify_interval(interval '1 usec' * my_col_usec) from my_table;`

How can this be accomplished in Redshift? I've looked at the docs on Redshift intervals (eg [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html)) but haven't found any relevant functions. The next best workaround I've come up with is to use `case` statements but I'd like something a bit more concise and, ideally, built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like

```
select (49275177354 * INTERVAL '0.000001 second');
```

or

```
select '00:00:00.000'::time+ (49275177354 * INTERVAL '0.000001 second');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!